# How can I access HDP cluster from kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I am using micro-service to access hadoop and hbase to get data but it's not accessible from pod.

It shows only:

```
INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hdpcluster.internal/10.160.0.2:8020. Already tried 3 time(s); maxRetries=45
```

IP `10.160.0.2` is accessible from all nodes and they are on GCP.

Comment: Where is your microservice running? Where is hadoop and hbase running?

Comment: microservice is running inside kubernetes clutser's pod. and hadoop and hbase is running on seperate cluster. Both cluster resides on GCP.

Comment: Added an answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to open a firewall rule to allow port 8020 on your Hbase nodes that your Kubernetes nodes can connect to them.  Something like this on your Hbase firewall rules (for your Hbase nodes):

[image: Sample firewall]